# How to make dataannotations outside the entities

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, wpf-controls, entity, data-annotations

I'm using Wpf and EntityFrameWork in my project. I wanted to use DataAnnotations since it is a better way to validate the data. I managed to make it in my entity files. For example one of my entities include these:

```
public partial class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public Employee()
    {
        this.Address = new HashSet<Address>();
        this.Certificate = new HashSet<Certificate>();
        this.ContactInformation = new HashSet<ContactInformation>();
        this.Course = new HashSet<Course>();
        this.Education = new HashSet<Education>();
        this.EmployeeTeam = new HashSet<EmployeeTeam>();
        this.Evaluation = new HashSet<Evaluation>();
        this.ExamInformation = new HashSet<ExamInformation>();
        this.JobTitle = new HashSet<JobTitle>();
        this.MilitaryService = new HashSet<MilitaryService>();
        this.Relationship = new HashSet<Relationship>();
        this.WorkExperience = new HashSet<WorkExperience>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }


    private string _CitizenId;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "CitizenId is required!")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+$", ErrorMessage = "Only numbers allowed")]
    public string CitizenId
    {
        get
        {
            return _CitizenId;
        }

        set
        {
            _CitizenId = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CitizenId"));
            }
        }
    }


    private int _RegNumber;
    [Required (ErrorMessage = "Registration Number is required!")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+$", ErrorMessage = "Only numbers allowed")]

    public int RegNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _RegNumber;
        }

        set
        {
            _RegNumber = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RegNumber"));
            }
        }
    }
    public Nullable<short> ResourceTypeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> EmployeeRoleId { get; set; }


    private string _FirstName;

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Name is required!")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$", ErrorMessage="Numeric expressions are not allowed!")]



    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return _FirstName;
        }

        set
        {
            _FirstName = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstName"));
            }
        }
    }

    private string _MiddleName;
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$", ErrorMessage = "Numeric expressions are not allowed!")]

    public string MiddleName
    {
        get
        {
            return _MiddleName;
        }

        set
        {
            _MiddleName = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MiddleName"));
            }
        }
    }


    private string _Surname;
    [Required(ErrorMessage= "Surname is required!")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$", ErrorMessage = "Numeric expressions are not allowed!")]



    public string Surname {

        get
        {
            return _Surname;
        }

        set
        {
            _Surname = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Surname"));
            }
        }
    }


    private int _CustomerNo;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer Number is required!")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+$", ErrorMessage = "Only numbers allowed")]
    public int CustomerNo
    {
        get
        {
            return _CustomerNo;
        }

        set
        {
            _CustomerNo = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CustomerNo"));
            }
        }
    }


    public System.DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }



    private string _BirthPlace;
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Birh Place is required!")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$", ErrorMessage = "Numeric expressions are not allowed!")]

    public string BirthPlace
    {
        get
        {
            return _BirthPlace;
        }

        set
        {
            _BirthPlace = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("BirthPlace"));
            }
        }
    }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime WorkBeginDate { get; set; }

    //indicates that whether the start  date is bigger than the end date which is a validation problem
  //  [CustomValidationsForDate("WorkBeginDate", ErrorMessage="Starting date cannot be bigger than the ending date")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> WorkEndDate { get; set; }

    private string _LogonName;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Logon Name is required!")]

    public string LogonName
    {
        get
        {
            return _LogonName;
        }

        set
        {
            _LogonName = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LogonName"));
            }
        }
    }

    private int _DistanceToWork;
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+$", ErrorMessage = "Only numbers allowed")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="This field is required!")]
    public int DistanceToWork
    {
        get
        {
            return _DistanceToWork;
        }

        set
        {
            _DistanceToWork = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DistanceToWork"));
            }
        }
    }
    public Nullable<bool> HasInternet { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> HasRemoteConnection { get; set; }
    public int MilitaryStatus { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DrivingLicense { get; set; }
    public bool IsSmoker { get; set; }


    public bool IsActive
    { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string LeavingReason { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }




    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Certificate> Certificate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ContactInformation> ContactInformation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Course { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Education> Education { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeTeam> EmployeeTeam { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Evaluation> Evaluation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ExamInformation> ExamInformation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<JobTitle> JobTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MilitaryService> MilitaryService { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Relationship> Relationship { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WorkExperience> WorkExperience { get; set; }


    //Following methos have been used in order to apply DataAnnotations


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Error { get { return String.Empty; } }

    public string this[string property]
    {
        get { return ValidateProperty(this, property); }
    }

    public static string ValidateProperty(object instance, string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyInfo property = instance.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        object value = property.GetValue(instance, null);
        List<string> errors = (from v in property.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<ValidationAttribute>()
                               where !v.IsValid(value)
                               select v.ErrorMessage).ToList();
        return (errors.Count > 0) ? String.Join("\r\n", errors) : null;
    }


}
}
```

So like I said I'm applying dataannotations inside the entities but what I want is doing that outside because whenever a change occurs in my database, all the entities will be refreshed so what I have here is not a dynamic structure. 
So could you please help?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Ege

Answer (score 0):

You should create a model (view model) class and map from your entities (domain models) to the view model.  AutoMapper can help speed this up.  You then put your annotations on your view models and use these in your views.

This means that if your entity model changes you just need to update the mapping.  It also means that you can create multiple different models for the same entity so your validation doesn't have to be the same for each view that uses it.